# Best way to test eventEmiters?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Suppose that I have a simple component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-test',
  template: '<div></div>'
})

export class test {

  @Output selected: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  public onSelect(event: any) {
    this.selected.emit(event.data);
  }
}
```

What's the best approch to test it ? I've seen with subscribe like this:

```
it('should emit the selected item', (done) => {

  myTest.selected.subscribe((result) => {

    expect(result).toBe('123');
    done();
  }
  //Act
  myTest.onSelect({data:'123'});
}
```

Or with a spy like this:

```
it('should emit the selected item', () => {

  spyOn(myTest.selected, 'emit');
  //Act
  myTest.onSelect({data:'123'});
  //Assert
  expect(myTest.selected.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('123');
}
```

The two constructs passes the tests. I think that the second one is simpler, so my question is: does the two constructs are equivalent ? Is there a reason to better use the fist test rather than the second and why ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They test the same thing different ways.

I agree your second form is easier to read because

1. The AAA syntax flows top to bottom instead of inside the callback
2. You are testing the direct effects (that `emit` is called)

This is in contrast to testing the indirect effect (`subscribe` is invoked) that isn't visible in the code.